# using group function inside group function

Tags: mysql, sql, function, group-by

My database:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id | group_id | inside_id | value +
+  1 |        1 |         1 |    50 +
+  2 |        1 |         2 |    12 +
+  3 |        1 |         1 |     4 + 
+  4 |        2 |         3 |   140 +
+  5 |        2 |         2 |    81 +
+  6 |        2 |         3 |    24 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    group_id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN MAX(inside_id) = inside_id THEN value ELSE 0 END) as sum_value 
FROM table 
GROUP BY group_id
```

Expected result:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ group_id | sum_value +
+        1 |        12 +
+        2 |       164 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I use this query in left join and that's why I don't know before, which values `inside_id` contains and I just need the sum of value when `inside_id` is maximal in current group, problem is that group function inside group function not work and cause "Invalid use of group function".

By the way `inside_id` for `group_id` contains only two possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT group_id, SUM(value) as sum_value 
FROM table A
Where inside_id = (select max(inside_id) from table B where a.group_id=b.group_id)
GROUP BY group_id
```

The `sub-query` will find the max `inside_id` for each `group_id`

Another approach using `correlated sub-query` and `conditional aggregate` some what similar to your current try.

```
SELECT group_id, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN inside_id = (SELECT Max(inside_id) 
                               FROM   table B 
                               WHERE  a.group_id = b.group_id) THEN value 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS sum_value 
FROM   table A 
GROUP  BY group_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option which uses a join with an uncorrelated subquery to identify, and then sum, records having the max `inside_id` for each group.

```
SELECT t1.group_id, SUM(t1.value) AS sum_value
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT group_id, MAX(inside_id) AS inside_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY group_id
) t2
    ON t1.group_id  = t2.group_id AND
       t1.inside_id = t2.inside_id
GROUP BY t1.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_id,SUM(value) as sum_value
FROM  table 
WHERE group_id<>inside_id 
GROUP BY group_id
```